# Queue giving the full data array instead of sending byte by byte in ESP32

Tags: c, timer, esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I'm trying to send the array that we get through UART and passing the array to the "hex_to_bin" function. The data received is perfect and this is also passed to the queue. I want only one byte at a time so that I can extract bit from it in the "turn_on_off" task and perform the timer functions. I used binary semaphore thinking that queue will wait and send the data, bit extraction is done successfully but I can't process timer functions. Please help me in this regard.

```
#include "main.h"

QueueHandle_t data_queue;

void turn_on_off(void *pvParameters)
{
  uint8_t bit;
  int data_index = 0;
  timer_start(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX);
  gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
  int bit_check = 0;
  int prev_bit_check;

  UartDataStruct UartDataStruct_Onewire;

  timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
  while (true)
  {
    if ((xQueueReceive(data_queue, &UartDataStruct_Onewire, portMAX_DELAY) == pdPASS))
    {
      // printf("Received data is : %s | len : %d\r\n",&UartDataStruct_Onewire.UartDataBuffer[0],UartDataStruct_Onewire.len);
      timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);

      while (true)
      {
        timer_get_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, &task_counter_value);
        // printf("Task counter value: %lld",task_counter_value);
        if (bit_check == 0)
        {
          if (task_counter_value > 200000) // 1000 count per ms
          {
            gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
            if (task_counter_value > 256000)
            {
              gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
              bit_check++;
              timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          for (data_index = 0; data_index < UartDataStruct_Onewire.len - 1; data_index++)
          {
            for (int itr = 7; itr >= 0; itr--)
            {
              bit = (UartDataStruct_Onewire.UartDataBuffer[data_index] >> itr) & 0x01;
              // ESP_LOGI("Onewire","Bit extracted: %d", bit);
              if (bit == 1)
              {
                for (prev_bit_check = bit_check; bit_check > prev_bit_check;)
                {
                  if (task_counter_value > 30000) // 1000 COUNT PER ms
                  {
                    gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
                    if (task_counter_value > 38000)
                    {
                      gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
                      bit_check++;
                      timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              else
              {
                for (prev_bit_check = bit_check; bit_check > prev_bit_check;)
                {
                  if (task_counter_value > 6000) // 1000 COUNT PER ms
                  {
                    gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
                    if (task_counter_value > 26000)
                    {
                      gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
                      bit_check++;
                      timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            printf("---------------\r\n");
          }
        }
        if (data_index == UartDataStruct_Onewire.len - 1)
        {
          bit_check = 0;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The way you calculate `bit` – how could it ever be anything else than 1 or 0 – so why test for 0 if it is not 1?

Comment: Your inconsistent indentation makes the code hard to read... Still: what appears suspicious to me is that you reset the counter on small values already – while the larger ones wouldn't catch up on then any more – unless waiting for the semaphore produces a sufficiently large delay.

Comment: It's actually pretty unclear to me what you actually *intend* to achieve. Apparently you *somehow* intend to toggle GPIO 2, but it looks pretty much to me as if you are losing the state in between. And how long should the semaphore be held? As long as toggling *all* bits occurs or just for toggling one single bit?

Comment: Within the `for`-loop you have `if(value > 30000) { value = 0; }` – it appears pretty unlikely to me that if you reset the counter in one `if` that it might get a sufficiently large value already in next loop run, so in that case only the very first bit actually would get evaluated at all. If you intend to *wait* for the timer you might rather try `while(value < 30000) {} value = 0; /*...*/`

Comment: Yes, actually I need the semaphore to held as long as all the toggling occurs for all bit for the received byte.

Comment: And on reading a 1-bit – do you want to set GPIO 2 to low for 30 ms and raise it up to high after further 8ms?

Comment: The output I'm trying to get is, for any word like 'HELLO' this will be passes through UART and will be processed like the ASCII value letter 'H' will be converted into its binary value and for that binary value GPIO should be toggled. The toggling time is, for bit '0' 6ms on time and 20 ms off time and for bit '1' 30ms on time and 8ms off time. Before every word a start bit of 200ms on time and 56 ms off time should be given.

Comment: A probably unrelated matter: I'm not feeling comfortable on messing with the counter's internal value for time measuring. Might be stable (not experienced with freertos), but I personally would prefer not doing so. Instead I'd rather store a timestamp at the beginning and calculate the difference to current value.

Comment: Can you help me to implement your idea, please?

Comment: OK, I see... It *cannot* work this way, though. You are trying to test with one single `if` – and if that one doesn't catch up, you simply go on – everywhere. Instead you need to *wait* until the desired time elapses. For this purpose you need *multiple ifs within a loop*. I personally recommend to write an explicit `wait` function to avoid code duplication. It might look as follows: `void busyWait(unsigned timerGroup, unsigned timerIndex, unsigned long /*long?* duration) { long timestamp = getCounter(); while(getCounter() - timestamp < duration) {} }`

Comment: Be aware, though, that such busy-waiting keeps CPU usage high! You tagged freertos – assuming there's support for multi-threading then there should be better ways to trigger the next action!

Comment: OK, forget about our `busyWait` (you'd possibly do that if you run your micro-controller without OS, which is what I'm actually familiar with) – instead [vTaskDelay](https://www.freertos.org/a00127.html) is what you need...

Comment: If we are not using delays, then please tell me how to proceed, I've been edited the code as you said.

Comment: You mean, not `vTaskDelay` as presented in the answer? Depends on what the OS allows you to actually interfere with... If you try from within a loop or different function calls (imagine you use a timer interrupt for this purpose, so this would apply for the interrupt service routine) you need to persist the current state (between loop runs or function calls), on interrupt firing/detecting timer elapsed you take the appropriate action and then advance the state accordingly.

Comment: I'd see two reasons for which you might want to have the one or the other; the interrupt possibly for having more precise timing (if OS allows access to at all), the other loop for parallelising multiple tasks within the same thread. If none of these apply I'd remain with the accepted solution, otherwise feel free to ask for further help.

Comment: I got the output as expected and thank you for your guidance @Aconcagua, I've shared my answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the information from the comments [vTaskDelay](https://www.freertos.org/a00127.html) is your friend here (you finally can drop the timer entirely):

```
xSemaphoreTake(data_semaphore, portMAX_DELAY);
// side note: you do not handle the case of the semaphore NOT having been taken! 

// assuming setting to low switches the LED on – if not, invert the values!

gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
vTaskDelay(200 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // see documentation
gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
vTaskDelay(56 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
for(bits...)
{
    if(bit == 1)
    {
        onTime = 30;
        offTime = 8;
    }
    else
    {
        onTime = 6;
        offTime = 20;
    }
    gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
    vTaskDelay(onTime / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
    vTaskDelay(offTime / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}
xSemaphoreGive(data_semaphore);
```

Note: Totally untested code, if you find a bug please fix yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "main.h"

QueueHandle_t data_queue;

void turn_on_off(void *pvParameters)
{
  uint8_t bit;
  int data_index = 0;
  timer_start(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX);
  int bit_check = 0;
  int prev_bit_check;
  int i = 0;

  UartDataStruct UartDataStruct_Onewire;
  while (true)
  {
    if ((xQueueReceive(data_queue, &UartDataStruct_Onewire, portMAX_DELAY) == pdPASS))
    {
      // printf("Received data is : %s | len : %d\r\n",&UartDataStruct_Onewire.UartDataBuffer[0],UartDataStruct_Onewire.len);
      timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
      gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
      while (true)
      {
        timer_get_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, &task_counter_value);
        //ESP_LOGI("","Task counter value: %lld",task_counter_value);
        if (bit_check == 0)
        { //ESP_LOGI("I inc: ","%d",++i);
          if (task_counter_value >= 200000) // 1000 count per ms
          {
            gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
            //ESP_LOGI("Start bit","Task counter value: %lld",task_counter_value);
            if (task_counter_value >= 256000)
            {
              gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
              bit_check++;
              timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
              //ESP_LOGI("Start bit","Task counter value 2: | Bit_check: %lld,%d",task_counter_value,bit_check);
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          //ESP_LOGI("I else inc: ","%d",++i);
          for (data_index = 0; data_index < UartDataStruct_Onewire.len - 1; data_index++)
          {
            for (int itr = 7; itr >= 0; itr--)
            {
            bit = (UartDataStruct_Onewire.UartDataBuffer[data_index] >> itr) & 0x01;
           // ESP_LOGI("Onewire","Bit extracted: %d", bit);
            timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
              if (bit == 1)
              {
                //ESP_LOGI("Bit '1'","Getting inside");
                for (prev_bit_check = bit_check; bit_check <= prev_bit_check;)
                { 
                  timer_get_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, &task_counter_value);
                  if (task_counter_value >= 30000) // 1000 COUNT PER ms
                  { 
                    gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
                    //ESP_LOGI("Bit '1' on-time","Task counter value: %lld",task_counter_value);
                    if (task_counter_value >= 38000)
                    {
                      gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
                      bit_check++;
                      timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
                     // ESP_LOGI("Bit '1' off-time","Task counter value: %lld",task_counter_value);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              else
              {
                for (prev_bit_check = bit_check; bit_check <= prev_bit_check;)
                {
                  timer_get_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, &task_counter_value);
                  if (task_counter_value >= 6000) // 1000 COUNT PER ms
                  { 
                    gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
                    // ESP_LOGI("Bit '0' on-time","Task counter value: %lld",task_counter_value);
                    if (task_counter_value >= 26000)
                    {
                      gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, true);
                      bit_check++;
                      timer_set_counter_value(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, 0);
                      //ESP_LOGI("Bit '0' off-time","Task counter value: %lld",task_counter_value);
                    }
                  }
                  //ESP_LOGI("Bit '0' on-time","Out of if");
                }
              }
            }
            //printf("---------------\r\n");
          }
        }
        if (data_index == UartDataStruct_Onewire.len - 1)
        {
          bit_check = 0;
          gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_2, false);
          xQueueReset(data_queue);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm... Three issues with: 1. This is a busy wait, i.e. it means high CPU consumption. If you only have one single thread anyway that might yet be (halfway?) fine, still I'd rather avoid. 2. Until reaching the upper/second time limit you continuously and repeatedly set the GPIO to false. Might not harm, still appears incorrect to me. 3. While waiting you re-calculate the action to be done again and again. You really rather should go with `vTaskDelay` *unless* there's a really good reason for not doing so (maybe not precise enough?).

Comment: *If* there is, I'd rather write my own [`waitFor` function](https://godbolt.org/z/rWc6jvWMe) and use it just as I used `vTaskDelay` in my answer. This will result in code much less complicated and thus much better maintainable...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).